# Getting error while integrating clerk in next js 14 Missing Clerk Secret Key or API Key

Tags: next.js, next-auth, clerk

I have added all the secret key and publishable key in .env.local as docs suggest in folderName/src in that I have added .env.local
but still I am getting error

`

```
 in layout.tsx I have  
import { ClerkProvider } from '@clerk/nextjs' export const metadata = {   title: {
    default: 'Learning',
    template: '%s |Learning'   },   description: 'Generated by Next.js', }

export default function ProfileLayout({   children, }: {   children: React.ReactNode }) {   return (
    <ClerkProvider  >
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
      <header style={{backgroundColor: 'floralwhite'}}>
        <p>Header</p>
        </header>
      {children}
      <footer><p>Footer</p></footer>
      </body>
    </html>
    </ClerkProvider>

  ) }
```

`

Comment: How did you fix this in the end?